# How to up to date umbraco.config

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I need to update some data in a page and this websites is using CMS Umbraco, so I change the umbraco.config but in the page is not have any change id this data, anybody can help me ?

Comment: You've asked a lot of questions and never marked any as correct? Theres a green tick next to all answers that you are meant to select to help others. Heres a helpful link for you http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 4):

The umbraco.config file is a cache file which will be generated if you change a page in the CMS.  To change a page, log in into the /umbraco/ folder and update the page you want to update.  Umbraco will update the database values and regenerate the umbraco.config file with the latest data.

Take care that the umbraco installation has write access to this file, otherwise the CMS won't be able to write the changes to this file.

You can also try to delete this file, Umbraco will recreate the file using the data from the CMS.

To refresh the cache, log in into the cms, right click on the "content" node and choose "republish entire site".  Then click OK.